# Class property does not added to HTML while openui5 converts XML

Tags: html, css, xml, sapui5, footer

I add "footerAlarms" value in XML view but in HTML version it does not appear in the browser. So what can I do to see the class footerAlarms in HTML view.

```
<footer class="footerAlarms">
            <Toolbar>
                <ToolbarSpacer/>    
                <Link text="{i18n>readMeOss}" press="openSourceFileDownload" class="sapUiMediumMarginBegin LinkOss"/>                                           
            </Toolbar>
</footer>


footer.footerAlarms {
    height: 42px !important;
    width:calc(100%-32px);
    margin:0 16px 0 16px !important;
    background: #FFFFFF !important;
    box-shadow: 
    0 1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.60),
    inset 0 -1px 0 0 rgba(115,100,90,0.16);
}
```

[image: browser image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My work around**

```
onAfterRendering : function(){
    $("footer").addClass("footerAlarms");
  }
```

**CSS**

```
.footerAlarms {
    height: 42px !important;
    // space is needed for the value inside braces below
    width:calc(100% - 32px);
    margin:0 16px 0 16px !important;
    background: #FFFFFF !important;
    box-shadow: 
    0 1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.60),
    inset 0 -1px 0 0 rgba(115,100,90,0.16);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot dot before footer.footerAlarms, so it should be:

```
.footer.footerAlarms {
    height: 42px !important;
    width:calc(100%-32px);
    margin:0 16px 0 16px !important;
    background: #FFFFFF !important;
    box-shadow: 
    0 1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.60),
    inset 0 -1px 0 0 rgba(115,100,90,0.16);
}
```

Edited 291117 15:27 :

Sorry, so try this:

```
.footerAlarms {
        height: 42px !important;
        width:calc(100%-32px);
        margin:0 16px 0 16px !important;
        background: #FFFFFF !important;
        box-shadow: 
        0 1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.60),
        inset 0 -1px 0 0 rgba(115,100,90,0.16);
    }
```

Comment: footer is an xml element. Not a second class value